# How can I intercept the file:// requests to provide a directory listing?

Tags: file, firefox-addon, protocols, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to replace the directory lists generated by Firefox by a custom one.

So, I need three things:

1. I need to know when Firefox tries to load a `file://` URI.
2. I have to test if that URI targets a directory or a file.
3. If the target of the URI is a directory, i have to prevent Firefox from generating the directory listing, and show my own directory listing instead.

It's the first point that is the most problematic:

- I read the documentation of the `nsIObserverService` but it doesn't do what I want (there is a `http-on-modify-request` but no `file-on-modify-request`)
- I tried to use the Jetpack's `addon-kit/page-mod` on `file://*` URIs, but it seems it doesn't allow me to verify if the URI targets a directory before loading my stuff.
- I read the documentation of the `nsIFileProtocolHandler`, but it doesn't help me.

So how can I intercept the `file://*` requests?

Does somebody have an idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I tried to use the Jetpack's addon-kit/page-mod on file://* URIs, but it seems it doesn't allow me to verify if the URI targets a directory before loading my stuff.

That's right. However, you can do the same thing that `page-mod` module is doing, namely listen to the [`document-element-inserted` observer notification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Observer_Notifications#Documents). Something along these lines:

```js
var events = require("sdk/system/events");
var urls = require("sdk/url");
events.on("document-element-inserted", function(event)
{
  var window = event.subject.defaultView;
  if (!window)   // XBL document?
    return;

  var url = urls.URL(window.document.URL);
  if (url.scheme == "file")
  {
    // A file:/// URL was loaded, do something with this window
  }
});
```

For reference: [`system/events` module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/system_events), [`url` module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/url).

> I have to test if that URI targets a directory or a file.

The `url` module also allows you to get the file path, and then you can use the [`io/file` module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/io_file) to access it:

```js
var files = require("sdk/io/file");
var path = urls.toFileName(url);
var isDir = files.exists(path) && !files.isFile(path);
```

> If the target of the URI is a directory, i have to prevent Firefox from generating the directory listing, and show my own directory listing instead.

That's the hard part. I don't think that you can prevent Firefox from generating the directory listing but calling `window.stop()` should have the same effect. You can then dynamically add your own contents to the window. You can use `files.list(path)` method to get a list of directory entries:

```js
window.stop();
var entries = files.list(path);
for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++)
  addEntry(window, path, entries[i]);
```

Comment: "observer-service" library is not exists anymore

Comment: @msangel: Sure, these code examples are ancient. I changed them to use the capabilities of the modern SDK modules.

Comment: Good to know that there exists `sdk/system/events` package. It was not simlpe to found it in documentation(I was unsaccessfull with this), so I used Services from `Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');`